# How to bind an imageSource from a List of Image items in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, maui

I'm developing an app that will soon have a server/DB. I want toaccomplish the binding between the List images and the xaml. Any idea of how to proceed?

```
 public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /** --------------------------------------------------------------------
    *                           Properties
    *  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    List<Image> images;
    public List<Image> Images
    {
        get { return images; }
        set { images = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Images)); }
    }
public Profile()
    {
        Images.Add(new Image());
        Images.Add(new Image());
    }


...



<ImageButton Source="{Binding Profile.Images[0].Source}" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="630"></ImageButton>
```

Comment: is `Image` a `Xamarin.Forms.Image`, or something else?  The XF Image is a UI control, and should not really be used like this.

Comment: Bind to list of strings (containing file paths), or list of `ImageSource`s. Make sure to define a **public property**. `public … { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of List you can use ObservableCollection. It also "notifies" when you manipulate the list (i.e. `.Add`, `.Remove`, ...)